# Что такое github.com и как им пользоваться?

Tags: git, github

Что я понял сам

github.com используется совместно с git для контроля версий разработки или для командной разработки

Вопрос - как начать пользоваться github.com что для этого нужно?

И есть ли аналоги?

Comment: в качестве близкого аналога можете посмотреть https://bitbucket.org/,  чуть дальше http://code.google.com, https://sourceforge.net и http://www.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 9):

Не ужели сложно поисковиком пользоваться?

Вот [Как начать работать с GitHub: быстрый старт](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125799/) читайте, когда прочтете и что то конкретно не будите понимать спрашивайте.

Answer (score 7):

Git - система контроля версий.
GitHub - один из множества ресурсов, где установлен Git.

Для того, чтобы начать пользоваться Git, тебе надо прочитать вводный тур. + По мере изучения смотри примеры в интернете. Информация тут:

http://githowto.com

http://git-scm.com/book/ru

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Аналоги есть. Можешь даже поднять свой собственный git-сервер.

Answer (score 3):

Два ответа хороши, на всякий случай добавлю про аналоги: gitorious.com, assembla.com, bitbucket.org, или даже GitlabHQ.
[Более развёрнутый список](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109440/best-git-repository-hosting-for-a-commercial-project)